# Searching every single word in different column within same table with a single query

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, mysqli

I have a `string`:

```
$searchkey="a b c";
```

I have three columns:

```
$column=array('column1','column2','column3');
```

I want to to check every word into those column and get a single query string. In order to get it, I did following... but it does not look that I want...I am very new to PHP, So I am stack. Can you please help to solve it or any other easy way to get a single query string !!!

```
$searchkey="a b c";
$words = EXPLODE(" ",$searchkey);
$column=array('column1','column2','column3');

foreach($column as $column){    
   for($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){
       $string1.=''.$column.' like %'.$words[$i].'% or ';
   }
   $string1 = SUBSTR($string1,0,STRLEN($string1)-4);
   $string2.= '('.$string1.') or ';

}
echo $string2= SUBSTR($string2,0,STRLEN($string2)-4);
```

It gives me:

> (column1 like %a% or column1 like %b% or column1 like %c%) or (column1
>   like %a% or column1 like %b% or column1 like %c%column2 like %a% or
>   column2 like %b% or column2 like %c%) or (column1 like %a% or column1
>   like %b% or column1 like %c%column2 like %a% or column2 like %b% or
>   column2 like %c%column3 like %a% or column3 like %b% or column3 like
>   %c%)

However, I would like to get:

> (column1 like %a% or column1 like %b% or column1 like %c%) or 
>   (column2 like %a% or column2 like %b% or column2 like %c%) or 
>   (column3 like %a% or column3 like %b% or column3 like %c%)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `$string1 = "";` statement as the first instruction in the body of the `foreach` loop, to reset it in every iteration instead of adding to it every time!

---

```
...
foreach($column as $column) {
   $string1 = ""; // <-- Add this line, and every thing will be fine :)
   for($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++) {
       $string1.=''.$column.' like %'.$words[$i].'% or ';
   }
...
```

Comment: Originally, I added $string1=''; and $string2=''; before the foreach loop, now I did $string1='' bellow the foreach loop, saw no changes except with an erros saying undefined string1

Comment: brother, could you little touch with my codes pointing out the position, where exactly I need to change.